# .. literalinclude:: from markers

Tags: python-sphinx, code-documentation

I am using [python-sphinx](/questions/tagged/python-sphinx) for documenting a C code. I am not interested in features offered by [doxygen](/questions/tagged/doxygen), however I sometime would like to include some snippets from the code-base.

The `.. literalinclude::` looks great, but the `:lines:` option is a bit weak especially if the code is edited afterwards.

I am thinking about a new option such as `:marker-start: <<<HERE` and `:marker-end: <<<END`.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `start-after` and `end-before` options. Below is an example.

example.txt:

```
# START
first line
second line
# END
third line
```

Markup:

```
.. literalinclude:: example.txt
   :start-after: # START
   :end-before: # END
```

This will appear in the output:

```
first line
second line
```

See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude.